# Copy the text to the Clipboard without using any input

Tags: javascript, html, clipboard

I just saw many articles in the web to find a solution to copy text to the Clipboard. But Every tutorials explain with inputs examples.

```js
  function GeeksForGeeks() {
            var copyGfGText = document.getElementById("GfGInput");
            copyGfGText.select();

            document.execCommand("copy");

            alert("Copied the text: " + copyGfGText.value);
          }
```

```html
  <input type="text" value="GeeksForGeeks" id="GfGInput">

         <!-- The button used to copy the text -->
         <button onclick="GeeksForGeeks()">Copy text</button>
```

But I need to copy just a simple text.
Is there a way to copy simple string from variable to the Clipboard?
example`

```
let text = "copy this text to the clipboard";
```

Comment: The research effort is huge here ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/setData

Comment: "copy just a simple text" does it mean you want to copy from other tags except for input?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should be able to do this with `document.createElement();` like this;

```js
function CopyMe(TextToCopy) {
  var TempText = document.createElement("input");
  TempText.value = TextToCopy;
  document.body.appendChild(TempText);
  TempText.select();
  
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(TempText);
  
  alert("Copied the text: " + TempText.value);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="CopyMe('The text here will be copied')">Copy text</button>
```

Let me know how this helps.

=============== UPDATE - March 2023 ===========

The execCommand method may not be available in all browsers so a better way to do this now would be;

```js
function copyToClipboard(text) {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(text)
.then(() => {
  console.log(`Copied text to clipboard: ${text}`);
  alert(`Copied text to clipboard: ${text}`);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(`Could not copy text: ${error}`);
});
}
```

```html
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('The text here will be copied')">Copy text</button>
```

This is a better and cleaner way to do same thing but if the website you're working on has a Content Security Policy (CSP) or other security settings that prevent access to the clipboard you will get errors (https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes).

Comment: This works perfectly. Note: Use `document.createElement("textarea");` if you have newline characters in the text.

Comment: This seems "hackish" for what should be a simple solution.  I've been digging around myself and this seems to be the only way as of now.

I'm OCD about having unused elements but another option would be to add a hidden field and change that data dynamically rather then injecting one.

If using a framework like Vue this may make more sense?

Comment: `document.execCommand` is deprecated according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the current solution only requires the use of
"navigator.clipboard" which also works in the current EDGE.

```
 navigator.clipboard.writeText('my text to be written to the clipboard ...')
                                                .then(() => { alert('Copy successful'); })
                                                .catch((error) => { alert(`Copy failed! ${error}`); });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/write

Comment: Chrome with Version 99.0.4844.51 gives me: 
Copy failed! NotAllowedError: Document is not focused.

Comment: @Fluchaa I've put a solution for your question below. Check it out please.

Answer (score 0):

Using Sarah code with improvement, asked by Fluchaa:

```
$("#myButton").click(function() {
    this.focus();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText("MY PLAIN TEXT")
                                   .then(() => { alert("Copy successful"); })
                                   .catch((error) => { alert(`Copy failed! ${error}`); });
});
```